# How to assert that json.dump was called with the correct arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm attempting to write a unit test using `PyTest` and `Mock` that tests that the correct arguments are being passed to json.dump

The function that houses the json.dump accepts 1 argument that is a list of `ids` that is used to make queries to the db. For each `id` 2 calls are made to retrieve tables that contain that same id. Then that information is formatted into a dictionary. At the end of the list, I pass the final dictionary to json.dump like so:

```
    with open(
        "./src/bloomberg/ecdpmm/bmpmsvc/read/serialize_change_set/serialize_change_set.json",
        "w",
        encoding="utf-8",
    ) as serialized_file:

        json.dump(response_json, serialized_file, default=object_handler, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

What confuses me is how, in another file, I can write a test cases asserts the correct arguments are being passed. Like I've seen code snippets that do something along the lines of:

```
json = Mock()

json.loads('{"key": "value"}')
>> <Mock name='mock.loads()' id='4550144184'>

json.loads.assert_called_with('{"key": "value"}')
```

When doing the `assertion` are the arguments (that I am mocking) being compared to the arguments being passed in my main file ? Are the functions above the correct approach to what I am trying to do ?

Any guidance/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the function I am trying to test:

```
def serialize_change_set(change_set_ids: list[int] | None = None) -> None:
    """
    Get a list of altered tables in the change set and serialize them
    """
    logger.info("serialize all the tables in the change set ")

    response_json = {}
    for cs_id in change_set_ids:
        response_json[cs_id] = {"Changed_Tables": {}}

        description = db.get_change_set_description(cs_id)
        response_json[cs_id]["Description"] = description

        altered_tables = db.get_change_set(cs_id)
        for table_name, table_rows in altered_tables.items():
            formatted_rows = [dict(row) for row in table_rows]
            response_json[cs_id]["Changed_Tables"][table_name] = formatted_rows

    with open(
        "serialize_change_set.json",
        "w",
        encoding="utf-8",
    ) as serialized_file:

        json.dump(response_json, serialized_file, default=object_handler, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: what do you want to test exactly? the arguments in the main file? also what is the point of testing `json.loads`? you should be testing your function which that lives inside instead

Comment: No, I'm trying to test the arguments being passed into `json.dump`. The code snippet that includes `json.loads` was something I came across while searching for answers

Comment: can you should your actual function definition you are trying to test?

Comment: Sure! Added it above

Comment: that function does a lot, you will have to mock the database calls as well. might make sense to split that function in to two, have the writing to the file be separate

Answer (score 0):

If you have a module (say, `my_module.py`) that does this:

```
import json


def my_function(response_json):
    with open(
        "serialize_change_set.json",
        "w",
        encoding="utf-8",
    ) as serialized_file:
        json.dump(
            response_json,
            serialized_file,
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4,
        )
```

Then you can write a test like this that mocks out `json.dump` and
then later tests to see how it was called.  In `test_my_module.py` we
have:

```
import my_module
from unittest import mock


def test_my_function():
    test_data = {"some": "value"}

    with mock.patch("my_module.json"), mock.patch(
        "my_module.open", mock.mock_open()
    ) as _open:
        my_module.my_function(test_data)

        my_module.json.dump.assert_called_with(
            test_data, _open(), sort_keys=True, indent=4
        )
```

We have to mock out both `json.dump` and the builtin `open` function
(because (a) we don't want our unit tests to create files, and (b) we
want to be able to match the value returned by `open` in our call to
`assert_called_with`).

---

Our test passing:

```
$ pytest -v
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.11.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python
plugins: anyio-3.5.0
collected 1 item

test_my_module.py::test_my_function PASSED                                                        [100%]

=========================================== 1 passed in 0.02s ===========================================
```

Answer (score 0):

ISTM that the best possible test for arguments to *json.dump()* is to run them through `_ = json.dump(*args, **kwargs)` to see if it raises an exception.

Since the two functions have the same internal logic, the *dumps()* function can serve as a validator for *dump* without having to write to disk.

Put that is a validation function and use Mock to attach the call.